# Same redux actions dispatched in quick succession

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have an application with like button. User can like multiple posts in quick succession. I send the action to update likecount and add like/user record through a redux action.

```
export const likePost = (payload) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "LIKE_POST",
    payload,
  });
};
```

In the saga on successful update, the control of action comes in both cases but LIKE_POST_SUCCESSFUL is triggered only for the last.

```
function* requestLikePost(action) {
  const { postId } = action.payload;
  try {
    const response = yield call(callLikePostsApi, postId);
    yield put({
      type: "LIKE_POST_SUCCESSFUL",
      payload: response.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: "LIKE_POST_FAILED",
      payload: error.response.data,
    });
  }
}
```

These are recieving action in reducer. The LIKE_POST is triggered two times as expected but not the LIKE_POST_SUCCESSFUL, its triggered only for the last though both reached .

```
case "LIKE_POST":
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: {},
       
      };
    case "LIKE_POST_SUCCESSFUL":
      updatedPosts = state.posts.map((post) => {
        if (post.postId === action.payload.postId) {
          return action.payload;
        }
        return post;
      });
      updatedLikes = [
        ...state.likes,
        { userName: state.profile.userName, postId: action.payload.postId },
      ];
      console.log("updatedLikes", updatedLikes, action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: updatedPosts,
        likes: updatedLikes,
        loading: false,
      };
```

API call

```
const callLikePostsApi = (postId) => axios.get(`/post/${postId}/like`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `takeLatest()` effect for your saga function `requestLikePost`? It will take only latest action call into consideration and aborts all the previous calls if it happens in quick succession.

> Use `takeEvery()` saga effect instead.

Comment: Thanks i was using takeLatest in saga. Since original request was triggered for both likes i didn't think in this direction. It was rightly cancelled.